# Write a program that calculates and outputs the first N odd Fibonacci numbers, separated by comma and space. N is entered from the standard input

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I am trying to write this program, but i think i am making some mistakes with the logic. [This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcC0F.png). Ok, so i run with a cycle to collect all the ODD numbers, but my last number is either 0 or some garbage value. I am fairly new to c++, i've spent more time on C and i assume i am not using the vector class right or my logic is trash. I spent so much time and i just can't figure it out. I am sure it is a pretty simple solution, but i cannot see what i am doing wrong. Thanks for your time!

```
main()
{
    int num; // how many odd numbers the user wants to see
    int first = 0; // first fibonacci number
    int second = 1; // second fibonacci number
    int next = 0; // basically the sum of the previous two numbers
    vector<int> holder; // a place to store the odd numbers
    holder.push_back(second); // adding 1, otherwise we would miss it
    cout << "How many ODD numbers would you like to see?:";
    cin >> num; // taking user's input

    int c, i;
    for (i = 0, i < num; i++) {
        next = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
        if ((next % 2) != 0) {
            holder.push_back(next);
        }
    }

    for (c = 0; c < num + 1; c++) {
        cout << holder[c] << "," << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, just paste it in your post!

Comment: I tried several times but it gets all messed up, i'm sorry :(.

Comment: @GiboGibonski check out [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/5610030) to see how you can properly add code to your question

Comment: @Shogunivar i will know for next time, thank you very much mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this: The first for loop runs `num` times, which is not long enough to find `num` many entries for `holder`. That means that `holder.size() < num`. In your second for-loop, you iterate even one number more than `num`, which means that you do illegal accesses within the vector, and you would do them even if it had `num` many entries (since `c` would become as large as `num`, which is not a legal index). Since a push_back enlarges the vector to a potence of 2 if it enlarges it, those are technically valid entries, but contain junk data as you see.

Simple fix:

exchange `for (i = 0, i < num; i++) {` with `while(holder.size() < num){`. (And `num+1` with `num` in the second loop)

Also, you might want to exchange `for (c = 0; c < num + 1; c++) {` by `for(unsigned int c=0; c < holder.size(); c++){`. Keeping the size correct is the responsibility of the vector class and should not be done from the outside, those two loops are different operations.

By the way, start to declare variables in the smallest scope possible (a for loop iterator for example in the loop) and divide your program in logic steps, like having a function `vector<int> create_odd_fibonacci_numbers(const unsigned int amount);` and `void print_vector(const vector<int>& vec);`. Makes debugging easier. Not in this small example perhaps, but you simply want to get used doing it that way.

Comment: that makes alot of sense now. Thank you very much, still one small problem - it has a runtime error somewhere. I tried debugging it, the program crashes when it reaches the while cycle. It is something about the condition holder.size<num, which i cannot understand.

Comment: http://www.cpp.sh/9md4j <<< works just fine for me. You put brackets behind size? num is set? Give the actual code and the error message.

Comment: I found my mistake, i got messed the loop somehow. Everything is running good now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Sorry man, i am new to this community :-D! Done, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

replace with this loop while printing values

```
 for(c=0;c<num;c++){
                cout << holder[c] << "," << " ";
            }
```

Comment: Works if i type 3 or 4. But everytime i type something greater like 5 or 6, i get garbage values again. And it is always the last one. For example if i type 5 i get 1,1,3,5,[garbage value]. If i type 6 i get: 1,1,3,5,13,[garbage value]. Could this be a problem somewhere in the memory with the vector's last item? Can't really figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int fibonacciRecursion(int n){
    if(n==1||n==2){
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacciRecursion(n-1)+fibonacciRecursion(n-2);
}

main()
{
   int num; // sum of how many numbers the user wants to see
   int i,c; // loop variable
   vector<int> holder;
   cout << "how many odd fibonacci numbers do you want to see:";
   cin >> num;
   for (i=1; i <= num*2; i++){
    if((fibonacciRecursion(i)%2)!=0){
        holder.push_back(fibonacciRecursion(i));
    }
  }

   for(c=0;c<num;c++){
    cout<<holder[c] << "," << " ";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I think i came up with a solution, but i don't think it's very efficient. So i run the loop num*2 times more, seems the mistake is there. Because we only save the odd numbers, but i forgot the loop still goes through and then some trash value is located in the last slot of the vector. So by running num*2 instead of just num times, i kinda assure myself there will not be any garbage placed in the vector. Still, i save more items in the vector, wasting memory for nothing. It works, but i think it could be a lot more efficient. Would be very happy to see what you guys think.